# How to get parent navigator in flutter not an ancestor?

Tags: flutter, navigator

I am facing getting parent navigator in flutter and I am trying this approach.

In login screen, when authentication is successful, app navigates to Home screen which has bottom navigator. bottom navigator has 3 tabs and each tab has multiple screen as child. To keep navigator independent between 3 tabs, I defined navigatorKeys for each tab.

And to navigate to detail screen of each tab, I am using this code snippet.

```
void _push(BuildContext context, {required String routeName}) {
    final routeBuilders = _routeBuilders(context);

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => routeBuilders[routeName]!(context),
      ),
    );
}
```

The problem is navigated screen overlaps bottom tab but my intention was to keep bottom navigation bar.
I think **Navigator** gets the ancestor navigator which is parent of both login screen and home screen and that's why child screen of tab navigator overlays bottom navigation bar.

[image: flutter inspection image]
As we can see in the screenshot, TimesheetPage is the child of MaterialApp not an Offstate TabNavigator.

I am not a veteran at Flutter so have no idea how to handle this at the moment.
It would be appreciated if someone could help me with this.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you understand what the structure of the widgets should look like? From the point of view of my experience, you have the maximum weird widget tree

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I believe TimesheetPage should be inside second red rectangle navigator but it belongs to ancestor...

Comment: I also cannot understand what effect you are achieving. According to your tree, I have a suspicion that you are using widgets without understanding their meaning. Why are you using the Stack after Scaffold? See examples, they are good in flutter https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html